# DSN-less connection sql-MS Access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to make a dsn-less connection in a java app i am working on but when i try to connect to the DB i get this error : ava.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

here's the code

```
 public void connection(){

   (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Κίμων
     try{


  Driver d =(Driver)Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance(); 
   Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Κίμων\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HairStyle\\HDB.accdb"); 

     }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     }            
 }
```

i've noticed that if i place the accdb file to me E: drive the error is gone.. can someone help me plz?

Comment: Try to provide a valid, compileable code part example!

Comment: You say it works if placed on the E: drive. What path, there? I ask because your C: path above has non-ANSI characters, and it's possible the driver has trouble with Unicode or non_ANSI path strings... or there could be another reason. Either way, please provide more info.

Comment: well i think that solved the problem David M... the problem is that the author(user) name is on Greek.. and propably that driver cant recognise it... ty for your comment.. that saved alot of work..